# $_POST don't give any result

Tags: php, html

I try with a little script on php but it doesn't give any result.

**example.html:**

```html
<form action="action.php" method="post">
 <p>URL <input type="text" name="url"></p>
  
 <p><input type="submit" value="OK"></p>
</form>
```

**action.php:**

```html
<html>
  <? echo $_POST['url'];?>
</html>
```

Even when the field of url is full, it doesn't give any result.

Comment: Add error reporting: `ini_set("display_errors", 1);
 error_reporting(E_ALL);` And tell us if you get any. Also make sure you have short open tags enabled or change it to `<?php`

Comment: where i have to add it  ?

Comment: Right at the top of your php file, but they need to be enclosed in php tags

Comment: Are short tags enabled on your server?

Comment: Can you all your data using `echo $_POST;`? To see if there a problem.

Comment: @mk10 are ther any errors? Use rizier123s' comment at the top to display any errors, providing PHP short tags are enabled, you should not be running into any problem. Your HTML form names match up in PHP. If truly no errors are present and the array is still empty, then run: `echo "<pre>"; print_r($_POST); echo "</pre>";` to display the entire post array

Comment: @aldrin27 **Warning** array to string conversion

Comment: @DarylGill sorry for that. Yeah you're' right.

Comment: @Rizier123  you mean like that : <?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
?>

<html>
 
<?php echo $_POST['url'];?>
</html>

Comment: it returns the content of action.php

Comment: @mk10 What does it exactly return?

Comment: <?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
?>

<html>
 
<?php echo $_POST['url'];?>
</html>

Answer (score 2):

First be sure that action.php is located in the same directory as the html file containing the form.

Second, change your php code to the following:

```
<?php echo $_POST['url']; ?>
```

**Regarding short tags:**

> When PHP parses a file, it looks for opening and closing tags, which
>   are  which tell PHP to start and stop interpreting the
>   code between them.
>
> PHP also allows for short open tag http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php

**Short tags example:**

```
<? echo $variable ?>
<?= $variable ?>
```

These do not contain the opening "<?php" and is discouraged per the quote above.

However, starting in 5.4 the second version of the short tags will always be on regardless of the short tag setting in the php.ini.  That means the

```
 <?= $variable ?>
```

will always be available.

**How to use short tags prior to PHP 5.4**

Open you php.ini file, search for "short_open_tag" and change the value to "1".
http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag

Answer (score 1):

you should use `<?php echo $_POST['url']; ?>` 
 this is standard tags
instead
`<? echo $_POST['url'];?>`

`<?  ?>`   is short tags, need short_open_tag enabled in php.ini

Answer (score 0):

```
change this :

 <html>
 <? echo $_POST['url'];?>
 </html>
```

by this :

```
<html>
<?php echo $_POST['url'];?>
</html>
```

**UPDATE :** to enable php short tags fast , at .htaccess the put the following :

```
php_flag short_open_tag on
```

Comment: it looks like short_open_tag issue

Comment: you can go to php.ini the short_open_tag=On

Comment: i do that but no result :/ , i'm confused o.O

Comment: did you restart your machine

Comment: you will find it as this short_open_tag = Off change it to short_open_tag = On then restart your server

Comment: I can give fast solution , just add this line to your .htaccess file :          php_flag short_open_tag on